# How does this 3.7 volt battery indicator work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI9yfB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If have found the above schematic for a battery charge indicator, but don't understand how it works (in particular without the use of comparators).
Can someone please explain?

Comment: You need to define better somehow. What do you want from the circuit that is better that what you show, is there problems in the circuit you show?

Comment: I couldn't match the title and the body.

Comment: Why do you think a 324 is an essential component of a battery indicator?

Answer (score 2):

LEDs are strongly non-linear, with minimal current flow or light output until a threshold forward voltage is reached, and then a rapid increase in both current and light for further relatively small increases in voltages.

As you can see from this [graph](https://softsolder.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/roygbuiw.png) the typical forward voltages of different coloured LEDs varies from colour to colour with the reds, oranges, yellows and greens relatively close (but in roughly increasing order), and blue/white significantly higher threshold.

[image]

Adding the standard signal diodes from one LED colour to another in the above circuit, introduces an extra voltage drop of ~0.6V per diode.  Combined with the different forward voltage for each colour, this means that a higher battery voltage is required to activate the respective LED colour in each of the parallel branches.

So for a battery charged at 100 % one would see ALL the LEDS activated, and with the battery almost discharged, one would barely see the red LED activated.

The circuit you quote is rather crude and consumes quite a lot of battery power just for the sake of showing the battery voltage but would probably suffice in a very basic application or where the battery consumption is not an issue ... It would not be recommended other than in an extremely desperate situation ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Much sharper cuts will have circuit below. Of course it can be done much better using more components and own power supply. By changing the upper resistors you change levels/thresholds. Use common transistors like BC547B or 2N3904 with beta >200. The 100 Ω change according Vf of LEDs you are going to use.

[image]